# WebIntent error using PhoneGap 2.4. Reference error: WebIntent is not defined?

Tags: android, cordova, webintents

I am trying to open pdf and ppt files in my phonegap application. i am using phonegap 2.4 and the latest version of WebIntent plugin. I did as told on
[Webintent](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WebIntent)

but i still get this error:

*Reference error: WebIntent is not defined*

here is part of my html head section:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/webintent.js"></script>
```

here is part of my config.xml file

```
 <cordova>
     ...
   <plugins>
     ...
    <plugin name="Globalization" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
    <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
    <plugin name="WebIntent" value="com.borismus.webintent.WebIntent"/>
   </plugins>
 </cordova>
```

here is js portion of the code where i use the plugin

```
    function openFile(filePath){
    window.plugins.webintent.StartActivity({
    action: WebIntent.ACTION_VIEW,
    url: filePath},
    function(){},
    function(){alert("failed to open file")} 
    );
    }
```

where filePath is something like "file:///mnt/sdcard/file.pdf"

Please someone tell me what am I doing wrong.
P.S.: I am pretty new to phonegap and eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in: `action: WebIntent.ACTION_VIEW,`

`WebIntent` used to be a global (yuck), but is now wrapped in a closure.

Since you are using `window.plugins.webintent` you will want to change it to something like:

```
function openFile(filePath){
  window.plugins.webintent.StartActivity({
    action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW,
    url: filePath},
    function(){},
    function(){alert("failed to open file")} 
  );
}
```

I have amended the plugin's documentation examples.

Answer (score 0):

Even with the comment of modify action: WebIntent.ACTION_VIEW with window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_VIEW failed to me.

What I did was directly put the value of WebIntent.ACTION_VIEW

In the webintent.js it is:

`WebIntent.ACTION_VIEW= "android.intent.action.VIEW";`

My code example:

```
window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({
        action: 'android.intent.action.VIEW',
        type: "application/pdf",
        url: "file:///storage/sdcard0/Mapfre/Documentos/readme.pdf"},
          function() {WL.Logger.debug(">> OK");},
          function() {WL.Logger.debug(">> ERROR");}
          );
```